# Избежать конфликтЫ или конфликтОВ?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Как правильно: конфликтЫ не всегда можно избежать или конфликтОВ не всегда можно избежать?

Answer (score 2):

Управление для глагола избежать можно посмотреть в словаре:

**ИЗБЕЖАТЬ — ИЗБЕГАТЬ** кого-чего (**не что!**). В городе её не любят... как-то избегают (С.-Щ.); Избегать опасности; Избежать встречи; Волки избегали проложенных человеком дорог (С.-М.).

Answer (score 1):

Глагол "избежать" управляет родительным падежом (не винительным), поэтому "избежать конфликтов".